# Tomcat JDBC Connector not detected

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

I am developing a simple Java app which works under Tomcat. As database, I have chosen MySQL and it communicates with the Tomcat server via JDBC Connector. According to the documentation, I have downloaded the connector from the MySQL website and put it under directory lib/ of Tomcat; also I have added the following description in server.xml:

```
<Context docBase="user-accounts" path="/user-accounts" reloadable="true" 
source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:user-accounts">
            <Resource driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
                initialSize="10"
                maxActive="100"
                maxIdle="50"
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000"
                minIdle="10"
                name="jdbc/accountsDB"
                password="password"
                removeAbandoned="true"
                removeAbandonedTimeout="55"
                testOnBorrow="true"
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/account_schema"
                username="user"
                validationInterval="34"
                validationQuery="select 1" />
        </Context>
```

But I get the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/accountsDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you have a typo but you have:

```
name="jdbc/accountsDB"
```

in the Context element but your code is looking for `jdbc/mydb`.

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo.